# Непонятная ошибка со словарём в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Решил сделать простенькую программу для просмотра характеристик разных машин в формате "модельМашины.информацияОМашине" в Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 на Python, а IDE пишет ошибку. Даже три. Хотя на деле всё должно работать. При запуске выдаёт ошибку, скриншот ошибки приложу.[image: Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 выдаёт такую ошибку при запуске]
[image: А это IDE выдаёт до запуска]
Вот сам код:

```py
chooseCar = input()
carModel = "";
typeOfCar = "";
for i in chooseCar:
    if i != ".":
        carModel += i;
    else:
        break
typeOfCar = chooseCar.replace(carModel, "", 1)
typeOfCar = typeOfCar.replace(".", "", 1)
carsList = (
    skodaFabia2011 = ( #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
        fullName: "Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011",
        year: "2011",
        countryOfAssembly: "Czech",
        body: "Wagon",
        doorsAndSeats: "5/5",
        weight: "1090",
        fullWeight: "1605",
        maximumSpeedReal: "165kmh",
        maximumSpeedSpec: "192kmh",
        acellerate: "0-100kmh - 10.5s",
        trunkCapacityMin: "505L",
        trunkCapacityMax: "1485L",
        length: "4247mm",
        width: "1642mm",
        height: "1498mm",
        wheelbase: "2451mm",
        trackFront: "1433mm",
        trackBack: "1426mm",
        clearance: "149mm",
        typeOfFuel: "Petrol 92-95",
        locationOfEngine: "Front, transverse",
        litersOfEngine: "1598cm",
        compressionRatio: "10.5",
        enginePowerSystem: "Distributed Inject",
        cylinders: "4",
        valves: "16",
        horsePower: "105hp",
        torque: "153nm",
        torqueAtRPM: "153nm/3800rpm",
        transmissionType: "Manual 5-Speed",
        driveWheels: "FWD",
        suspensionFront: "Independent, spring-loaded",
        suspensionRear: "Semi-independent, spring-loaded",
        tireSize: "195/55",
        diskSize: "R15",
        brakesFront: "Ventilated disc",
        brakesRear: "Drum",
        fuelConsumptionUrban: "9.1L - 100km",
        fuelConsumptionSuburban: "5.6L - 100km",
        fuelConsumptionMixed: "6.9L - 100km",
        octaneOfFuel: "Minimum: AI-92, Recommended: AI-95",
        fuelTankCapacity: "45L",
        ) #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
    )
print(carsList[carModel[typeOfCar]])
```

Comment: skodaFabia2011 переменная?

Comment: @СергейШашко это словарь. Можно сказать переменная.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Не переживайте за назначение программы. Если вам указывают на ее бесполезность, игнорируйте это, если это только не дают показать что такое уже существует и показывают вам готовое решение. А вот  того, как долго вы изучаете и другой информации, не связанной с вопросом, лучше избегать

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, постараюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас скобки не те, а ещё skodaFabia2011 должна быть обрамлена как строка
Ну и как и всё остальные параметры

```
carsList = {
    "skodaFabia2011": { #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
        "fullName": "Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011",
        "year": "2011",
        "countryOfAssembly": "Czech",
        "body": "Wagon",
        "doorsAndSeats": "5/5",
        "weight": "1090",
        "fullWeight": "1605",
        'maximumSpeedReal': "165kmh",
        "maximumSpeedSpec": "192kmh",
        "acellerate": "0-100kmh - 10.5s",
        "trunkCapacityMin": "505L",
        "trunkCapacityMax": "1485L",
        "length": "4247mm",
        "width": "1642mm",
        "height": "1498mm",
        "wheelbase": "2451mm",
        "trackFront": "1433mm",
        'trackBack': "1426mm",
        'clearance': "149mm",
        'typeOfFuel': "Petrol 92-95",
        'locationOfEngine': "Front, transverse",
        'litersOfEngine': "1598cm",
        "compressionRatio": "10.5",
        "enginePowerSystem": "Distributed Inject",
        "cylinders": "4",
        "valves": "16",
        "horsePower": "105hp",
        "torque": "153nm",
        "torqueAtRPM": "153nm/3800rpm",
        'transmissionType': "Manual 5-Speed",
        'driveWheels': "FWD",
        'suspensionFront': "Independent, spring-loaded",
        'suspensionRear': "Semi-independent, spring-loaded",
        'tireSize': "195/55",
        'diskSize': "R15",
        'brakesFront': "Ventilated disc",
        'brakesRear': "Drum",
        'fuelConsumptionUrban': "9.1L - 100km",
        'fuelConsumptionSuburban': "5.6L - 100km",
        'fuelConsumptionMixed': "6.9L - 100km",
        'octaneOfFuel': "Minimum: AI-92, Recommended: AI-95",
        'fuelTankCapacity': "45L",
        } #Skoda Fabia MT1.6 2011
    }
```

Comment: Выдаёт то же самое, только ошибка теперь не на =, а на :

Comment: Я обновил, проверьте ещё раз

Comment: Спасибо, просто я пробовал также как в примере всё брать в кавычки, только скобки оставил обычные. Проблема решена.